# IIS won't activate WCF Service, 404 error

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7.5

I have a WCF Service that will only expose HTTP Endpoints, my App.config is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>  
  <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "C:\Users\Developer\Documents\ProjectName\Servicelog.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" />
    <services>
      <service name="Project.ServiceOne">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/Project/ServiceOne" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Project.IServiceOne"/>
      </service>
      <service name="Project.ServiceTwo">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/Project/ServiceTwo" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Project.IServiceTwo"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"/>
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I'm running IIS 7.5 (Windows 7 x64 - The full blown Programs and Features one, not Express) to the Default Web Site, the Project application.

I can browse to the .svc file and it will tell me the MEX endpoint is not enabled which is fine: It's the behavior i want over that aspect; The problem comes when i try to POST to `http://localhost/Project/ServiceOne/ServiceMethod`. The method exists in the Service contract and implementation and is also decorated in the interface as a WebInvoke but POST'ing to it will only return HTTP 404's. Decorating a test method with GET and browsing to it results in a 404 served by MapRequestHandler.

What is wrong with my App.config file?
How can i make those endpoints work?

As requested, the Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceOne
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       UriTemplate = "MyMethod")]
    List<String> MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your decorated interface?

Comment: @RealityDysfunction Posted a simplified version: all the methods in the interface have the same annotations configured almost the same way

Comment: I am not familiar with the GET method of communication with WCF because you often need to tweak the UriTemplate to get it to work, it is actually easier to get it to work with the POST method. If you change the method to POST and take out the UriTemplate and it still doesn't work then it is indeed web.config that's the issue.

Comment: It was POST before, i made it GET so i could test with plain browsing

Comment: I don't think you can set end point address in that way and post to that URL. RESTful WCF still need to have .svc in URL, and then you can use URL rewrite to remove .svc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup proper behaviors:

```
<services>
  <service name="Project.ServiceOne" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Project.IServiceOne" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseaddress="http://localhost/Project/ServiceOne">
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  <service name="Project.ServiceTwo" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Project.IServiceTwo" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseaddress="http://localhost/Project/ServiceTwo">
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>    
</services>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">         
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>        
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```