# WCF Service 404 Error on server but works fine locally

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, webforms

I have read a number of other threads on SO, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162996/iis-wont-activate-wcf-service-404-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941620/wcf-service-404-error-on-browser) but I have been unable to figure out the issue.

Both of my WCF services work fine locally, but give a 404 error when on the server:

[image]

Here is the Javascript code:

```
  $("#starRating").on('rating.change', function (event, value, caption) {
    var walkID = getUrlVars()["WalkID"];

    var score = $('#starRating').val();
    alert(walkID + " " + score);
    window.UserID = '<%=HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(this.User.Identity.GetUserId())%>';
    SaveRatingService.Save(score, walkID, window.UserID);
```

Here is my service:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class SaveRatingService
{
  [OperationContract]
  public void Save(string score, string walkID, string loggedInUser)
  {       
    ....
    return;
  }
}
```

Here is how I've registered it (MasterPage):

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>...</Scripts>                
      <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebServices/SaveRatingService.svc" />
      </Services> 
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Originally, I did have it on the page with the Javascript page in a `ScriptManagerProxy` but I moved it to see if that would solve the issue.

And finally here is my master page service configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DogWalks.WebServices.SaveRatingServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="DogWalks.WebServices.PostcodeFillAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="DogWalks.WebServices.SaveRatingService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="DogWalks.WebServices.SaveRatingServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="DogWalks.WebServices.SaveRatingService"  />
      </service>
      <service name="DogWalks.WebServices.PostcodeFill">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="DogWalks.WebServices.PostcodeFillAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="DogWalks.WebServices.PostcodeFill" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

AS mentioned, it runs fine locally. When I try and follow the path to the service (first screenshot), the path indeed leads to a 404 error.

On investigation of the file, I see that a script is added:

[image]

But, as mentioned in the 404 error it's not found. Why does the script add `/js`, which indeed is a directory that does not exist.

Comment: are you using bundling/minification?

Comment: @DanielA.White are you referring to the `BundleConfig`? I've uploaded it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tNB83c4E), if you wouldn't mind taking a look.

Comment: i'm guessing if you turn that off, it might work.

Comment: @DanielA.White Ok it's worth a go :). What's the best way to turn it off? From master page?